# Multithreading opengl app in visual studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am implementing mutlithreading opengl application in visual studio.

Here is my code:

```
void temp(void *a)
{


    /* create a window */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glutCreateWindow("Application");


    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    /* callback for mouse button changes */
    glutMouseFunc(mousebutton);

    /* callback for idle function */
    glutIdleFunc(doIdle);

    /* do initialization */

    glutMainLoop();

}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    myinit();
     _beginthread(temp, 0, (void*)0 );
    Sleep( 100000000000000);
     return 0;
}
```

If I create single thread with beginthread call, it works fine but if i call beginthread multiple times, it terminates immediately. I am not getting where i am going wrong.
Also, what is equivalent call of pthread_join in windows? how can i avoid that sleep in main ?

Comment: neither Windows (`VOID WINAPI Sleep(_In_  DWORD dwMilliseconds);` nor Linux (`unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`) supports `100000000000000`. On Windows you may use `INFINITE (0xFFFFFFFF)` to obtain an endless Sleep. However I'm running out of thoughts what the purpose of an endless Sleep would be.

Comment: @Arno: To me it is pretty clear, the OP does not want the application to reach the end of `main (...)` before the thread finishes. But there are much easier ways of blocking until a thread reaches a desired state, such as `WaitForSingleObject (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with opengl is that is **not thread safe**, and it is highly recommended to do everything on the main thread. when you call `_beginthread` the second time, a second thread will start will override the display functions that were set by the first thread. `GLUT` was not design to be used in such and you app might terminate because of a failsafe system inside `GLUT`

If you want to have multiple windows the you need to use use other api to handle the second windows , but the opengl context is still the same. You ca try [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) to achieve this , i know that has good support for multiple viewports.

Avoiding the `sleep` function in your case is very easy, you just call `temp` instead of `_beginthread` and that's it for the main function. Later on you can spawn more thread but you must stay away from opengl calls unless you are on the main thread.

Comment: OpenGL is perfectly thread safe. It is so thread safe in fact, that you have to go out of your way to share any resources between threads. To that end, newer versions of the API have all the fixings you would expect from a world-class API for synchronization between threads.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman probably on windows, i've seen a lot of wired stuff on mobile and i would personaly not venture in the depths of multithreading with the rendering apis (except if this is a "feature" from marketing, probably not even then)

Comment: @debonair: You don't; at least you don't do multithreaded OpenGL. You can use multithreading as much as you want, but you should keep all OpenGL operations to a single thread. There are *zero* performance gains in trying to multithread OpenGL; everything gets parallelized for free for you, and trying to be smarter than the system will make things worse, actually.

Comment: @datenwolf: actually i have ray tracing app which i want to multithread